# Watch $scope on factory using $http angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-scope, factory

I am trying to watch a change of value that is fetched from a factory using `$http`.

Here is my factory: (it simply returns a list of videos from the backend)

```
app.factory('videoHttpService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var service = {};

    service.getEducationalVideos = getEducationalVideos;

    return service;

    function getEducationalVideos() {
        return $http({
            url: 'api/video/educational',
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    }
}]);
```

Here is my controller:

```
app.controller('videoCtrl', ['$scope', 'videoHttpService', 
                         function ($scope, videoHttpService) {

    videoHttpService.getEducationalVideos().then(function (result) {
        $scope.educationalVideos = result;
    });

    $scope.$watch($scope.educationalVideos, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log(oldValue, newValue);
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            $scope.educationalVideos = newValue;
        }
    });

}]);
```

This does not work. I get `undefined`, `undefined` in the `console.log`.

Any insight of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you need to $watch for 'educationalVideos' instead of $scope.educationalVideos. I don't know your specific use case but it probably makes more sense to trigger your event with an additional .then() block after your request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to watch a `$scope` element, you have to do:

```
$scope.$watch('educationalVideos', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(oldValue, newValue);
    if (newValue !== oldValue) {
        $scope.educationalVideos = newValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: I've updated to this, but the oldValue log is still undefined all the time. and when a video is added to the list, the watch function does not update the $scope unless the page is refreshed

Comment: What do you mean by 'When a video is added to the list'. In the code you provided, you make a GET call only once in your controller.

Comment: Yes, i realise now that my example above is not complete, sometimes the video list will be updated.

Comment: no worries though, your answer helped me fix the problems :)